# php curl - result different from browser

Tags: php, curl

Im trying to get data from this url: http://www.fler.cz/shop/dara-bags?f14=2&onpage=72

When I open it in the browser, there are 72 items on the page, but when I try it via curl there is only 18. So it seems that "onpage=" parameter doenst work. But parameter "f14=" which is setting number of displayed page is working. Why is second parameter not working? Thank you.

Here is the code:

```
$source = "http://www.fler.cz/shop/dara-bags?f14=2&onpage=72";

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $source);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

$data = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
echo $data;
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass it in as an array

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
$source = "http://www.fler.cz/shop/dara-bags"
$data = array('f14' => '2', 'onpage' => '72');
$handle = curl_init($source);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_exec($ch);
```

Or you can use the code below to send GET request

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
$source = "http://www.fler.cz/shop/dara-bags?f14=2&onpage=72";  
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$source);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);

$output=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $output;
```

Comment: I thing the problem might be in redirection. First time I try to access page server redirects me to "http://www.fler.cz/shop/dara-bags?f14=2" so without onpage parameter.

Comment: You need to fix the redirect on your url. There seems to be a redirect when you go to your original url: http://www.fler.cz/shop/dara-bags?f14=2&onpage=72 to http://www.fler.cz/shop/dara-bags?f14=2 - you should go to your cms and stop the redirect and retry your curl request. It's bouncing to the redirect.